# How to get user selected string value in Android Popup dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog

In my application i am displaying a popup with dynamic texts from map. Now when user clicks on that String I need to get the selected value.Below is my code.

I have a button, on click of i will display a dialog.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:onClick="loadDialog"
        android:text="@string/continue_text"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
```

**dialog code**

```
public void loadDialog(View view) {
        calUtil.contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        HashMap<String, String> aMap;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(findViewById(R.layout.custom));
        CharSequence[] items = aMap.keySet().toArray(new String[calMap.keySet().size()]);
        builder.setTitle("abcd").setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //EditText input = (EditText) dialog.findViewById("myInput");
                dialog.toString();
                findViewById(which);
                }
        });
        builder.show();
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `which` returned in `onClick()` is the index of the selected item.

In your case, getting the string value associated that would be `items[which]` (you may need to make `items` `final` to ensure access within `onClick()`)